# Is CFUUIDCreate thread-safe?

Tags: core-foundation

Is `CFUUIDCreate` thread-safe? Didn't see anything about that in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the current 10.8.2 source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.12/CFUUID.c), it's certainly intended to be thread-safe.  The body of the function uses a `LOCKED()` function to `dispatch_sync` all the real work onto a single serial GCD dispatch queue. Simultaneous calls from multiple threads would therefore be serialized.

If you're interested in earlier versions of Mac OS X, you can find the code [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com). Unfortunately Apple doesn't release the source code of CoreFoundation on iOS, but it's probably safe to assume that it's similar to the OS X version.